# Flutter Auto update Textfield input to listview

Tags: flutter, listview, textfield

I will appreciate if anyone can help with how to update input value to listview like below attached GIF:

[image]

Basically my TextField is like this:

```
TextField(
                                                                    keyboardType:
                                                                        TextInputType
                                                                            .multiline,
                                                                    maxLines:
                                                                        null,
                                                                   
                                                                    controller:_controllerPassPhrase,
                                                                  )
```

And my listview is like this:

```
ListView.separated(
                                            separatorBuilder:
                                                (context, index) => Divider(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    ),
                                            itemCount:
                                                data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                              
                                              return Card(

                                              Text" Input field should come here when send button clicked ",

                                              );
                                            })
```

So whenever user input anything inside my Textfield I will like it to immediate go to the listview like the GIF fiel attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `List` of `Strings` (in this example named `data`) and populate it with your input messages.
**UPDATE based on your request in the comment section** You can have `List` of your custom type that contains `username` and `comment`, like so:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final _controllerPassPhrase = TextEditingController();
  final _controllerUsername = TextEditingController();
  List<UserWithComment> data = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              child: ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Text(
                      data[index].username + ": ${data[index].comment}",
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'username'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              controller: _controllerUsername,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'comment'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              controller: _controllerPassPhrase,
              onSubmitted: (value) => setState(() {
                if (_controllerUsername.text.isNotEmpty && value.isNotEmpty) {
                  data.add(UserWithComment(_controllerUsername.text, value));
                }
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserWithComment {
  final String username;
  final String comment;

  UserWithComment(this.username, this.comment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what about if the value I'm, add from ```data.add(value)``` is more than one?

Comment: I assume that you are asking what about if you want to add few values at once, then you have `addAll` instead of `add` method.

Comment: I will add ``` addAll ``` for two different TextField?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand your question. Please describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have two TextField with FullName and Comment when the user input and click send I will like to add them to listview.

Comment: Then your `List` doesn't needs to be of type `String`, it can be of some other type (like your custom class that has `user` and `comment` in it). So when you add your username and comment you can store it in that `List` of that type (class).

Comment: Can you please help update your answer in respect to this?

Comment: I have updated it. Adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks I can see ```  data.add(UserWithComment(_controllerUsername.text, value)); ``` is for adding  to ``` _controllerUsername``` what about  for ``` _controllerComment```

Comment: You get `username` from `_controllerUsername.text` and `comment` from `value` of `onSubmitted` `TextField` attribute and you pass them to `UserWithComment` constructor and add it to your `data` List. I think that I properly answered your question and that this thread is becoming too long. Enough from me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243273/discussion-between-mideveloper-and-ante-bule).